# Add a hoverable circle over a D3 chart plus tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, charts, frontend

I'm trying to customize a D3 chart and I'm running into a few issues.

I want to add a circle that navigates the chart and shows a tooltip with data but none of the methods I've tried so far have worked. I've tried appending a circle and a tooltip in my code but they won't show up. This is exactly what I'm trying to achieve, but in my own code, it just doesn't work:
https://bl.ocks.org/alandunning/cfb7dcd7951826b9eacd54f0647f48d3

I think this piece of code is the issue in my case and I don't know how to change it up or what to do about it:

```
    var focus = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "focus")
        .style("display", "none");

    focus.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 4.5);

    var rect = focus.append("rect")
        .attr("x", 9)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("fill", "yellow");

    var text = focus.append("text")
        var text = rect.append("text")
        .attr("x", 10)
        .attr("y", 10);
```

Here's a fiddle of my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/3Lje1f4w/

Comment: You've appended the focus but that isn't enough. You need code to listen for the mouse movement and update the position of the focus. Look at the last two code blocks from the example link you provided.

Comment: Feel free to also look at my example, I made a while back. https://jsfiddle.net/9j4kqq1v/5/ . Smokey is correct, you are not listening for mouse move events, so your tool tip is never going to be updated upon moving the mouse.